# getServerSideProps (Next Js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a next js frontend and a Graphql server on the backend, it works great with SSG but when I am using getServerSideProps it is making a request ( hitting the server ) only first time we visit any page and not on every refresh. Is this normal in SSR? ( Everything is in context of Production build)

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {


  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query Movies {
        movies{
          id
          name
          image
        }
      }
    `,
  });
  

  
  return {
    props: {
      parks: data.movies,
    },
 };
}
```

Comment: How did you check that it was hitting the server only the first, not every page load? Could you please explain your checking process here?

Comment: Maybe there is some caching going on somewhere, that is returning the same (old) value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Information provided, no it is not normal while doing SSR. According to the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). If you export a function called getServerSideProps (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.
So, the page should be loaded with latest data each time you reload the page. If its not happening as expected there might be some problem either in your fetching mechanism or data updating mechanism.